# How to read values from multiple application configuration files in c#?

Tags: c#, app-config, config

I am having two different `application configuration` files in my project.
I need to read values from these two `config` files in my code.   Searched a lot and found most of the answers are: use `ConfigurationManager`.  But I can't read the second `config` file in my code.  Please help on this.

Example: 
1. `app1.config`
2. `app2.config`

how to read the value of the `app2.config`?

Comment: This is probably get roundable, but your real problem is you are not following the convention. If one app needs another app's config file, it's not an app config file. Just have a file with some other name, putt the common values in it, have both apps read and write to it.

Comment: I need these separate to read them separately in my code.

Comment: Not my point. Reading an xml file in code is trivial, reading two is trivial, having two app.configs, is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast I found the way to handling `multiple configuration files`, the only way is use the SECTION handling within the  main `app.config` file.

The best way is first understand .NET configuration.  The best source is http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16466/Unraveling-the-Mysteries-of-NET-2-0-Configuration

Really hard for the first time to understand, once you are clear with this idea you can do wonders using configuration files in .NET.  This is the only solution I found throughout the   internet.

Thank you,
Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

The app will use the config file named YourExcecutable.exe.config which is by default the file App.config included in your (executable) project. Note, that .NET only loads one config file for the whole application. You cannot use multiple configuration files (i.e. one per library project) without coding.

1. You can use postbuild events and different solution configurations to copy one or another App.Config file to the output folder
2. You can use the ConfigurationManager Class to load an alternate config file by code.

Reference:

[Handle multiple configuration files](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5606/Handle-multiple-configuration-files)

[Managing Multiple Configuration File Environments with Pre-Build Events](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx)

Comment: can you please give an example on the option 2?

Comment: Check my answer with updated section. Hope this would help you.

Comment: `System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.File = "App2.config";`  here If I need to write some thing to app2.config then will it work?

Comment: I got exception called: `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`  when I tired to read a value from `app2.config` file.

Comment: I have shared a link with you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5606/Handle-multiple-configuration-files, there is a class name AnyConfig. Just create that class in your project and use it as mentioned in that link. There is a demo project in the same link that would be a helpful resource.

Answer (score 0):

Never used the app.config in .NET but another solution would be using Xml(XmlReader, XmlWriter) from the System.Xml namespace and you can create a tag for Configuration and use as many configurations as you like, all this in one file. e.g.

```
<Configuration name="app1">

//here you would have your 1 configuration
</Configuration>

<Configuration name="app2">

//here you would have your 2 configuration
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Is that possile within app.config?

Comment: Im not sure because ive never used app.config(which itself uses xml) but since its predefined for configuration files id guess its xml tags are predefined too, so i dont think its possible(i may be wrong but if it was possible you would have found it already)